# RabbitMQ: vhost stopped and error 500 after emergency shutdown

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Sometimes in docker, after emergency container shutdown, RabbitMQ service stop vhost, and only way to fix and start it, is recreate it with same settings. But after last crash vhost dissapear from vhost list in web cp, and every cmd in console with it create only new errors:

```
 rabbitmqctl add_vhost /
Adding vhost "/" ...
Error:
failed to set up vhost '/': {failed_to_start_vhost_on_nodes,
                             [{rabbit@capital_rabbitmq,
                               {error,
                                {shutdown,
                                 {failed_to_start_child,rabbit_vhost_process,
                                  {error,
                                   {{{badmatch,
                                      {error,
                                       {"/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient",
                                        eexist}}},
                                     [{rabbit_msg_store,init,1,
                                       [{file,"src/rabbit_msg_store.erl"},
                                        {line,729}]},
                                      {gen_server2,init_it,6,
                                       [{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},
                                        {line,548}]},
                                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                       [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]},
                                    {child,undefined,msg_store_transient,
                                     {rabbit_msg_store,start_link,
                                      [msg_store_transient,
                                       "/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L",
                                       undefined,
                                       {#Fun<rabbit_variable_queue.2.44586449>,
                                        ok}]},
                                     transient,30000,worker,
                                     [rabbit_msg_store]}}}}}}},
                              {rabbit@capital_rabbitmq,
                               {error,
                                {shutdown,
                                 {failed_to_start_child,rabbit_vhost_process,
                                  {error,
                                   {{{badmatch,
                                      {error,
                                       {"/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient",
                                        eexist}}},
                                     [{rabbit_msg_store,init,1,
                                       [{file,"src/rabbit_msg_store.erl"},
                                        {line,729}]},
                                      {gen_server2,init_it,6,
                                       [{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},
                                        {line,548}]},
                                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                       [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]},
                                    {child,undefined,msg_store_transient,
                                     {rabbit_msg_store,start_link,
                                      [msg_store_transient,
                                       "/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L",
                                       undefined,
                                       {#Fun<rabbit_variable_queue.2.44586449>,
                                        ok}]},
                                     transient,30000,worker,
                                     [rabbit_msg_store]}}}}}}}]}

rabbitmqctl restart_vhost -p /
Trying to restart vhost '/' on node 'rabbit@capital_rabbitmq' ...
Failed to start vhost '/' on node 'rabbit@capital_rabbitmq'
Reason: {:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :rabbit_vhost_process, {:error, {{{:badmatch, {:error, {'/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient', :eexist}}}, [{:rabbit_msg_store, :init, 1, [file: 'src/rabbit_msg_store.erl', line: 729]}, {:gen_server2, :init_it, 6, [file: 'src/gen_server2.erl', line: 548]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}, {:child, :undefined, :msg_store_transient, {:rabbit_msg_store, :start_link, [:msg_store_transient, '/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L', :undefined, {#Function<2.44586449/1 in :rabbit_variable_queue>, :ok}]}, :transient, 30000, :worker, [:rabbit_msg_store]}}}}}


rabbitmqctl add_vhost /5
Adding vhost "/5" ...
DONE

 rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
Listing vhosts ...
/3
/
/5
/2


rabbitmqctl delete_vhost /
Deleting vhost "/" ...
Error:
{{:badmatch, {:error, {'/shared/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@capital_rabbitmq/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient', :eexist}}}, [{:rabbit_vhost, :delete_storage, 1, [file: 'src/rabbit_vhost.erl', line: 204]}, {:rabbit_vhost_sup_sup, :stop_and_delete_vhost, 1, [file: 'src/rabbit_vhost_sup_sup.erl', line: 102]}, {:rabbit_vhost_sup_sup, :"-delete_on_all_nodes/1-lc$^0/1-0-", 2, [file: 'src/rabbit_vhost_sup_sup.erl', line: 79]}, {:rabbit_vhost_sup_sup, :delete_on_all_nodes, 1, [file: 'src/rabbit_vhost_sup_sup.erl', line: 79]}, {:rabbit_vhost, :delete, 2, [file: 'src/rabbit_vhost.erl', line: 152]}, {:rpc, :"-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-", 5, [file: 'rpc.erl', line: 197]}]}


 rabbitmqctl add_vhost /5
Adding vhost "/5" ...
Error:
{:vhost_already_exists, "/5"}
```

[image: web cp]

I know that rabbitmq store data in files and there should be ability to clear information from files to "reset" information connected with vhost, but it important not to delete users of Rabbit, bcs I dont have information about their passwords and don't know how to restore them after

Answer (score 0):

1. rabbitmqctl stop_app
2. delete all folders inside rabbitmq data :

- /mnesia/host@folder/msg_stores/vhosts/*
- /mnesia/msg_stores/vhosts/*

3. rabbitmqctl start_app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).